# "Uncaught Error: View type "timelineDay" is not valid" fullCalendar version 3.9.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

Here is my code:

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
<script>
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here, month,agendaWeek
        defaultView: 'timelineDay',
        header: {
            left: 'prev',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'next'
        },
        minTime: '10:00:00',
        maxTime: '18:00:00'
    });
</script>
```

And I get the error in my console of "Uncaught Error: View type "timelineDay" is not valid".

The version I am using is 3.9.0 but it also doesn't work for 3.5.1
My jQuery version is 3.3.1

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `defaultView: 'timelineDay'` you need the [scheduler](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/scheduler) plugin.

You must download it and add it to your document.

```
<link href='fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='scheduler.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='moment.js'></script>
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script src='scheduler.js'></script><!-- <<< New plugin here -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Old solved questions. 
Same problem with all the scripts. 
There was a conflict between a plugin and the script.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you solved it? I've downloaded the new fullcalendar-scheduler-4.4.0, and it doesn't have scheduler.js, but separately includes all the individual plugins. I've linked them, but they work only if I instantiate it without jQuery (that too with issues). With jQuery, I get the same error in this question.